# Connection to some websites fail on fresh installation

Tags: networking

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS but now some websites are unreachable. I first noticed the problem during my Android Studio install when the Android SDK add-on list couldn't be reached but later I while researching noticed that while some websites like google.com would load, others like stackoverflow and askubuntu.com wouldn't.

The PC is connected via Ethernet into a Switch into a WiFi Repeater which admittedly is kind of a wonky setup but it has never caused any issues while Windows 7 was installed.
I have set the IPv4 DNS to 8.8.8.8 in case it was connecting to a bad DNS Server but left the setting for IPv6 on automatic.
I'd appreciate any help. If you need any more information I'd obviously be glad to provide that.